# Change button colour when hovering over with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, hover, bind

I'm trying to make a widget with buttons that change colour when I hover over them with my cursor. Using code I found on the Internet I'm trying to write a small test program that can do this. I want to be able to activate the colour switching when I left-click and deactivate it when I right-click. I'm able to activate it but it does not deactivate when I right-click.

```
import tkinter

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.mouse_pressed = False
        self.root.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.OnMouseDown)
        self.root.bind("<ButtonRelease-3>", self.OnMouseUp)

        self.Hover1 = tkinter.Button(root,text="Red color", bg="SystemButtonFace")
        self.Hover1.pack()

        self.Hover2 = tkinter.Button(root,text="Yellow color", bg="SystemButtonFace")
        self.Hover2.pack()



    def do_work(self):
        if self.mouse_pressed:
            self.Hover1.bind("<Enter>", lambda event, h=self.Hover1: h.configure(bg="red"))
            self.Hover1.bind("<Leave>", lambda event, h=self.Hover1: h.configure(bg="SystemButtonFace"))

            self.Hover2.bind("<Enter>", lambda event, h=self.Hover2: h.configure(bg="yellow"))
            self.Hover2.bind("<Leave>", lambda event, h=self.Hover2: h.configure(bg="SystemButtonFace"))

    def OnMouseDown(self, event):
        self.mouse_pressed = True
        self.do_work()

    def OnMouseUp(self, event):
        self.mouse_pressed = False
        self.do_work()

root=tkinter.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

How do I deactivate it so that the colour stops changing? Also would it be possible to make is so that it is only active while the left mouse button in pressed in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not deactivated because the buttons are still bound to the events, so you need to unbind them. Try this:

```
    def do_work(self):
        if self.mouse_pressed:
            self.Hover1.bind("<Enter>", lambda event, h=self.Hover1: h.configure(bg="red"))
            self.Hover1.bind("<Leave>", lambda event, h=self.Hover1: h.configure(bg="SystemButtonFace"))

            self.Hover2.bind("<Enter>", lambda event, h=self.Hover2: h.configure(bg="yellow"))
            self.Hover2.bind("<Leave>", lambda event, h=self.Hover2: h.configure(bg="SystemButtonFace"))
        else:
            self.Hover1.unbind("<Enter>")
            self.Hover1.unbind("<Leave>")
            self.Hover2.unbind("<Enter>")
            self.Hover2.unbind("<Leave>")
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `do_work()` method does nothing when `mouse_pressed` is `False`. You should add some functionality when it is `False`.

```
def do_work(self):
    if self.mouse_pressed:
            ...
    else: 
        #unbind events from both buttons
        self.Hover1.unbind("<Enter>")
        self.Hover1.unbind("<Leave>")

        self.Hover2.unbind("<Enter>")
        self.Hover2.unbind("<Leave>")

        #return their color to original state
        self.Hover1.configure(bg="SystemButtonFace")
        self.Hover2.configure(bg="SystemButtonFace")
```